# How can I easily switch channels and pull data from a Kiethley DMM via GPIB?

Tags: python, gpib

I am in the process of writing a simple DAQ program that will record data from various sources and save them to a csv file while providing live plotting. It has gone well aside from one problem that has been kicking my butt.

One of the places I have to pull data from is an older Kiethley 2001 DMM with a scan-2001 10 channel scan card in it. Using Pymeasure and a Prologix USB to GPIB adapter, I can easily communicate with the unit but I can't figure out what string of GPIB commands I need to use in order to simply change to a particular channel, record the value on display, then move on to the next channel without interfering with the DMM's current settings. The different channels include voltage readings, amperage, temperature, and resistance that was already set up in the meter prior to this project.

Project is being written in Python3.7 and is being implemented on a Raspberry Pi 3B+

I know the communication is working properly because I can send an IDN? and get the unit information and ROUT:SCAN:INT? will show that all 10 channels are available.

```
data = keithley.ask(":DISP:DATA?")

print(data) #shows whatever is currently on display at the DMM

chan1 = keithley.ask(":ROUT:SCAN:INT?")

print(chan1) #provides a list of channels and shows all 10 of them
```

Comment: Have you looked at the reference manual?  The answers seem to appear in chapter 4.10 [here](https://doc.xdevs.com/doc/Keithley/2001/2001-M-900-01.pdf).

Comment: I have read through that reference manual, and maybe I'm not understanding the terminology but it seems like there are commands for getting the data (like the :READ? command) for the current channel. the 2001-tcscan manual https://cdn.testequity.com/documents/pdf/keithley/2001-TCSC-man.pdf explains how to program a channel to read in a particular way, but I can't find any way to just change channel without having to reprogram the entire channel every time.

Answer (score 0):

Check the results of
:ROUTe :STATe?
To see what’s available.

:ROUTe :OPEN ALL
and then triggering might get you all the channels at once. Read the output as a text array instead of individual numbers to check you aren’t just ignoring multiple results.